# How do I transfer remembered logins between browsers?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, twebbrowser

Okay so I've run into a bit of situation, I currently have the need to be able to transfer an active login between a program I made with visual studio which uses a web browser control to Internet Explorer so that the user can transition seamlessly between the two phases of my program's automation.  Any suggestions at all on how this might be done would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have code-level access to the web application itself?

Comment: I was just using the default webbrowser control in visual studio.

Comment: Is it your web application though, and therefore are you able to implement something on the website itself? Or are you restricted to only being able to change the desktop application?

Comment: the web application itself is not my own, im just writing a program to automate some features and it requires me to use the program and IE both with the same user.

Comment: Can I recommend adding that to the question itself? Comments may not be preserved, and two of the three answers give a solution that simply isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have never needed something like this but I think I would save PC name / IP / MAC Address to the database and hold the active/passive information accordingly.

Comment: What if you don't have access to the server database?

Answer (score 0):

Authorization and session keys which keeps user signed in to the website are probably stored inside the cookies, so you just need to transfer them from your program to the Internet Explorer. You can get your cookies (implying you're using WebClient) like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class), and set'em in the IE like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185171/use-cookies-from-cookiecontainer-in-webbrowser).

Comment: I'm going to look into those links and try it right way and I'll let you know how it works out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use session based key in Url with short expiration time. Something like:
`http://myhost/myservice?myarg=myvalue&sessionId=<sessionId>&sessionKey=<randomSessionKey>`

Be sure to generate random randomSessionKey for each session though.

It will even work between different browsers.