# Automatic login when run the program second time

Tags: vb.net

Recently try to use a webbrowser component.
when I click button, it will navigate to `facebook.com`. after I login on first time and stop the program. and then when I run the program second time I don't need to fill the email and password. why I don't need to fill an email and password textbox ? thanks

Here's the code

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("m.facebook.com")
End Sub

End Class
```

Note: I will delete this post, because it doesn't help the community. Just my curiosity. Thanks

how do i need to re-type the email password again when 2nd starting the program

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. The first is to save the `CookieContainer` associated with the `WebBrowser` to disk and reload it when you restart your program. There is no straightforward way to serialize cookies to disk or other storage method - that is up to you.
2. Instruct the `WebBrowser` object to make use of the user's Windows profile Internet Explorer cookie collection which is shared with Internet Explorer and other programs that also opt-in to sharing state (I do not know if this also applies to the Edge browser, I suspect it does not). See here for instructions on how to do this: [Use cookies from CookieContainer in WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185171/use-cookies-from-cookiecontainer-in-webbrowser)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I found this quite interesting and informational. Didn't know you could manage/handle the `WebBrowser`'s cookies this way.